# How do i add a message in Ajax success function

Tags: ajax, cart

This is my HTML

```
<div class="top-item-grid-body" id="item-grid-${entry.entryNumber}"></div>
```

This is my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              data:"",
              url: 'cart/delete?cartEntryNumber='+entryNbr,
              success: function(){
                  $("#item-grid-"+entryNbr).remove();



              }
        })
```

I have to display a message saying that "Your cart is empty" when all the items are removed..How do i do this in Ajax success function??

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
  $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          data:"",
          url: 'cart/delete?cartEntryNumber='+entryNbr,
          success: function(){
              $("#item-grid-"+entryNbr).remove();

              alert("Your cart is empty");
          }
    })
```

Comment: Hi ..I have not articulated my problem properly...I havve resolved it anyways thanks